# Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence of positive real numbers such that $\text{lim} \big(\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}\big) = L>1$. Then $\{x_n\}$ diverges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence of positive real numbers  such that $\text{lim} \big(\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}\big) = L>1$. Then $\{x_n\}$ diverges.

My attempt:

Since $L> 1$ write $L = 2k +1$ for $k>0$. Choose $\epsilon = k$. Then there exists a natural number $N$ such that $n \geq n$ implies $ L - k < \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} < L + k$. Therefore, $\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} > 1 + k$, i.e. $x_{n+1} > x_n (1+k)$ for all $n \geq N$.

Now we see that $$x_{N+m} > x_{N+m - 1} (1+k) > x_{N+m - 2} (1+k)^2 > \cdots> x_N (1+k)^m$$ for all positive integer $m$.

By Bernoulli's inequality we have $x_{N+m} > x_N (1+ mk)$ for all positive integer $k$.

Now I want to know how to conclude that $\{x_n\}$ diverges. I know that one way for this is to show $\{x_n\}$ is  not bounded, which is by definition for each $M>0$ there exist a natural number $N$ such that $n \geq N$ implies $|x_n| > M$.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Choose any number $c$ such that $1<c<L$. From the definition of a limit it easily follows that there is some $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}>c$ for all $n\geq n_0$. Without loss of generality we might assume that $n_0=1$. Then for each $n$ we have:

$x_{n+1}>cx_n>c^2x_{n-1}>c^3x_{n-2}>...>c^nx_1$

Since $c>1$ and $x_1>0$ the sequence $c^nx_1$ tends to $\infty$ when $n\to\infty$. Hence $x_n\to\infty$ as well, as we have shown that its elements are even larger.

Answer (score 1):

$N$ is fixed and so is $k\gt 0$.

You have got $x_{N+m}\gt x_N(1+k)^m\gt x_N(1+mk)$ for all positive integers $m$.

Note that RHS $\to \infty$ as $m\to \infty$ (i.e., RHS can be made arbitrarily large by choosing $m$ large enough).

It follows that $x_{N+m}$ is arbitrarily large and hence the sequence $\{x_n\}$ is not bounded.